# How to modify a curve so that it reference another curve

Tags: references, curve-fitting

Let's say we have a curve A with 50 time points (max = 60, min = 1). One way I can do is to standardize the values of the curve and make the range become [0,1] instead of [1,60].

However, I have another curve B with 50 time pints (max = 34, min =3). I want to use curve B as a reference. That is, standardizing A by B (that what I think...what I want to do is to relate curve A to B).

Does this make sense? How should I do this?

Comment: It might make sense--but unfortunately it can make sense in a lot of different ways.  Could you perhaps supply a small worked example to illustrate what you mean?

Comment: I find this question quite unclear. Why does "relate curve A to B" mean in detail?

Comment: For example. I want to standardize A in term of B. In general, A and B have no relationship. However, if we standard A in term of B. Then A is sorted of affected by B.

Comment: Is this your question?  "What would the coordinates of curve A become if the values of Xa and Ya were mapped, respectively, to the ranges of Xb and Yb?"

Comment: Yes, I think that's right.

Comment: What are A and B? Are they time-series vectors? If so, you can simply normalize both to a standard range like [0-1].

Comment: A and B are different curve with different maximum and minimum value. but they have the same length in x-axis (let's say 50 points). I want to reference curve A to curve B. (i.e., the value of A at each point at x-axis is relative to B). In other word, this is like standardization, but not 0-1 anymore.

Comment: I still don't understand what A and B are. I believe that you could get quicker results if you define your task more clearly. Are they (the values in A and B) coordinates of 50 2D points? or are they the values of an N-dimensional variable at 50 different times (my first _guess_ was N = 1), so are they 50xN (or 50x2) matrices, or 50x1 vectors? In either case, why don't you want to normalize between 0-1? Maybe another approach could be expressing B in terms of the ratio to A, so `B2=B./A`. But I'm still writing imaginatively since I have no idea what problem are you trying to solve :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, for example, A = [1 2 3 2 1 5 8 9 10 15 12 11 10 4 5]. B = [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.5 0.9 0.10 0.6 0.4 0.3 0.2]. Each A and B has 15 time points with certain values.